# Can back end server applications utilize the userinfo endpoint to retrive end-user claims in OpenID Connect?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

I have 3 applications,

1. Client Application(RP)
2. OpenID Provider(OP)
3. Mediation Server(MS)

The client Application can authenticate and retrive id_token and authorization token, The authorization token is then used by RP to call OP by passing it in the header. This request will then be forwarded to the Mediation Server(MS) by OP. The MS requires acess to end-user information. Simply passing them as query params or in request body is not an option.But the authorization token sent by the RP can still be accessed by the MS. Is it wrong to use OP's userinfo endpoint by MS to retrive user claims, since [openID Connect docs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) only mention userinfo endpoint to be used by Client Applications(RP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes, it is a valid use case.

User info endpoint is OAuth 2.0 token protected endpoint defined by OpenID Connect. It more or less behaves similar to token introspection endpoint defined by OAuth 2.0 ([OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)) providing token holder the ability to obtain authenticated end user information.

From your application perspective, you have two parts of the client. One the end user fronted part which actually obtain the access token and ID Token. Then you have a backend portion (MS as you defined) which rely on tokens to perform some validations (ex:- Email validation against a know DB). So basically MS being part of your application, this is still in scope for the term **CLIENT**.

An alternative to this is to use self contained access tokens. They will come in form of a JWT (similar to ID Token) and usually can be configured to have necesary user information. Advantage with that is you can possibly avoid MS to OP call for user information and rely on JWT integrity (note - of course you need public key from OP but this can be cached for sometime)

Comment: To add to what @Kavindu Dodanduwa has mentioned about MS belonging to the scope of **Client** , https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.1 clearly define that the term "Client" does not imply any implementation characteristics. Also JWT in this case could be considered as a future proof solution as it can also contain information about RP along with end-user information, that can be carried over to MS.

Comment: @PhatMan exactly.! Always refer specification to clear doubts.